# Bash Script that cd to a directrory?

Tags: python, linux, bash

How do you write a bash script or python script to cd to a directory based on a parameter where all parameter directory starts with abc and is in parent directory xyz? Example usage,

```
bashcd.sh abcFilename
```

The above searches for the directory inside parent directory xyz and changes current directory to abcFilename.

Comment: Can you say what you mean by going to a directory?

Comment: In bash the command is `cd`. But you seem to know that already. What are you asking?

Comment: Is this question really about **using** a script (whose source code is not shown in the question), or about **writing** such a script?

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that (changing directory in the parent shell) with a shell *script*. You need to do that in some shell *function* (or by sourcing some command file, see `.` & `source` shell builtins, or evaluating something, see `eval` shell builtin).

Because a script is running in its own process (see [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html)), and the [chdir(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/chdir.2.html) system call affects the current process (and future *children*) but not the parent (shell) process.

Consider reading [*Advanced Linux Programming*](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) for more detailed explanations. See also [credentials(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/credentials.7.html) & [capabilities(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabalities.7.html)

Answer (score 0):

Its not clear what you are looking for. I am guessing this may be what you want, I may be wrong.

```
cd xyz/$(ls xyz/ | grep abcFilename)
```